# Why is my calculation of the chromatic polynomial of $P_4$ coming out wrong?

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, coloring

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. Denote by $N_k$ the number of partitions of $V$ that give $k$ independent sets. Then we have that the chromatic polynomial is $\pi_G(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n N_k x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots (x-k+1).$

For the path with $4$ vertices, $P_4$, we have that $N_1 = 0, N_2 = 1, N_3 = 2, N_4 = 1$. Then by the sum above $\pi_{P_4}(x) = x^4 - 4 x^3 + 6 x^2 - 3 x$. But the chromatic polynomial is supposed to be $x(x-1)^3$. What's wrong?

Comment: $N_3=3$........

Comment: If $V=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $E=\{ab,bc,cd\}$ then the partitions into $3$ independent sets are $\{\{a,c\},\{b\},\{d\}\}$ and $\{\{a,d\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ and $\{\{b,d\},\{a\},\{c\}\}$.

Comment: That formula with $N_k$, that's the hard way to find the chromatic polynomial of a path. I don't recommend using it.